# ARKit – Hiding objects behind a wall

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit

I have an idea for AR app, and I noticed that in most AR apps the objects are not hided through the wall, is it possible for example I pinned the AR portrait in my room, and it is only can be seen if I go there, not through the walls?

I have no experience in AR, just about to learn it.

Thank you.

Comment: Didar, have you already implemented this approach?

Comment: @ARGeo Hey! Not yet. Because I am new to AR, just interested how it actually works, but thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

it's simple way to do this, you have to detect plane (in your case a wall) and setup for

```
node.geometry.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = []
node.renderingOrder = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hide all your objects behind a wall using three different approaches for wall creation: SCNBox(), SCNShape() with extrusion, or SCNGeometry(). Whatever you choose, just assign empty instance property `.colorBufferWriteMask` to it. And `.renderingOrder` instance property must be `-1`. Node with a negative value of rendering order is rendered first.

```
let wallNode = SCNNode()
wallNode.geometry = SCNBox(width: 15.0, height: 3.0, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
wallNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)

//wallNode.geometry = SCNShape(path: NSBezierPath?, extrusionDepth: CGFloat)
//wallNode.geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [SCNGeometrySource], elements: [SCNGeometryElement]?)

wallNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = []
wallNode.renderingOrder = -1
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(wallNode)
```

Hope this helps.